# Java - My Huffman decompression doesn't work in rare cases. Can't figure out why

Tags: java, arrays, byte, huffman-code, compression

I just finished coding a Huffman compression/decompression program. The compression part of it seems to work fine but I am having a little bit of a problem with the decompression. I am quite new to programming and this is my first time doing any sort of byte manipulation/file handling so I am aware that my solution is probably awful :D.

For the most part my decompression method works as intended but sometimes it drops data after decompression (aka my decompressed file is smaller than my original file).

Also whenever I try to decompress a file that isnt a plain text file (for example a .jpg) the decompression returns a completely empty file (0 bytes), the compression compresses these other types of files just fine though.

Decompression method:

```
    public static void decompress(File file){
        try {
            BitFileReader bfr = new BitFileReader(file);
            int[] charFreqs = new int[256];
            TreeMap<String, Integer> decodeMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
            File nF = new File(file.getName() + "_decomp");
            nF.createNewFile();
            BitFileWriter bfw = new BitFileWriter(nF);
            DataInputStream data = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));

            int uniqueBytes;
            int counter = 0;
            int byteCount = 0;
            uniqueBytes = data.readUnsignedByte();

            // Read frequency table
            while (counter < uniqueBytes){
              int index = data.readUnsignedByte();
              int freq = data.readInt();
              charFreqs[index] = freq;
              counter++;
            }

            // build tree
            Tree tree = buildTree(charFreqs);

            // build TreeMap
            fillDecodeMap(tree, new StringBuffer(), decodeMap);

            // Skip BitFileReader position to actual compressed code
            bfr.skip(uniqueBytes*5);

            // Get total number of compressed bytes
            for(int i=0; i<charFreqs.length; i++){
                if(charFreqs[i] > 0){
                    byteCount += charFreqs[i];
                }
            }

            // Decompress data and write
            counter = 0;
            StringBuffer code = new StringBuffer();

            while(bfr.hasNextBit() && counter < byteCount){
                code.append(""+bfr.nextBit());

                if(decodeMap.containsKey(code.toString())){
                    bfw.writeByte(decodeMap.get(code.toString()));
                    code.setLength(0);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            bfw.close();
            bfr.close();
            data.close();

            System.out.println("Decompression successful!");

        } 

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("test");
        compress(f);
        f = new File("test_comp");
        decompress(f);
    }
}
```

When I compress the file I save the "character" (byte) values and the frequencies of each unique "character" + the compressed bytes in the same file (all in binary form). I then use this saved info to fill by charFreqs array in my decompress() method and then use that array to build my tree. The formatting of the saved structure looks like this:

```
   <n><value 1><frequency>...<value n><frequency>[the compressed bytes]
```

(without the <> of course) where n is the number of unique bytes/characters I have in my original text (AKA my leaf values).

I have tested my code a bit and the bytes seem to get dropped somewhere in the while() loop at the bottom of my decompress method (charFreqs[] and the tree seem to retain all the original byte values).

EDIT: Upon request I have now shortened my post a bit in an attempt to make it less cluttered and more "straight to the point".

EDIT 2: I fixed it (but not fully)! The fault was in my BitFileWriter and not in my decompress method. My decompression still does not function properly though. Whenever I try to decompress something that isn't a plain text file (for example a .jpg) it returns a empty "decompressed" file (0 bytes in size). I have no idea what is causing this...

Comment: I know a fair bit about the huffman algorithm but I (and everyone else) am reluctant to read your entire post as it's not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Ok, I have now edited my post and tried to make it less cluttered and a bit shorter. I don't know how I would post a compilable version of my code though since my decompress method requires the compressed file in order to work (plus the tree and everything else) and it can't just have a dummy string as input instead (at least I think that that would not work).

Comment: Ever heard of the Single Responsibility Principle? It means to split up your code into pieces that do just one thing, which makes it more maintainable and separately testable. A method that handles both file I/O and decompression has at least 3 responsibilities, hence why feeding it a dummy input doesn't really work. (in your particular case I find 7, tough some are already separate, like `fillDecodeMap`)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus I fixed it! There was a bug in my BitFileWriter where it refused to write the last remaining bits when compressing if those last bits only consisted of zeros. But the other problem still remains... when I decompress something other than a plain text file (for example a .jpg) I get back a completely empty "decompressed" file (0 bytes).